# Specific Items in Nested RecyclerView does not load until scroll

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, rx-java2

I create a nested recycler view for a nexflix type application which calls categories on the API first then makes another call to API to list each items in category.

The first call is done on the a Fragment and the second call is made with in Adapter of the Fragment of the first one

First Call

```
subscription = MAS.api().getCategories()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe( c -> {

            Arrays.sort(c.toArray());

            categoryList.addAll(c);




            adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0,categoryList.size() );


            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }, error -> {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setMessage(error.getMessage())
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, (dialog, which) -> getActivity().finish())
                    .show();
        });
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

SecondCall

```
MAS.api().getSpecificCategory2(categoryName)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(s -> {
        catalogueList.addAll(                                                                                                                                         s);
                adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(-1, catalogueList.size());

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //horizontalRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mValues.size()-1);


                Collections.sort(catalogueList,   (o1, o2) -> {
            int i = o1.publication_date_time.compareTo(o2.publication_date_time);

            return (i != 0) ? -i : i;
        });
    });
```

These are the layout files

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/Black">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/categoryName"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Title" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_height="278dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalRecyclerView"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/textColorPrimary"
android:padding="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#76B6C4"

        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivThumb"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="233dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:minHeight="233dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catalogueName"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/ivThumb"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:text="Title"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"

            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_cloud_download"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


     </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Specific nested recycler Views don't get populated until I scroll out of view and return. I tried adding Scroll View but that did not help.  I tried to limit the number of items in the recycler children but it still did not help. It is just two child recyclerView that don't show until I scroll past them and return

I see no specific errors to fix

Comment: It's unclear where your calls are taking place and where you're actually updating your recylerview adapter. Is `categoryList` a shared reference between your fragment and recycler view?

Comment: Yes. Categorylist is a collection where the api payload is saved.

Comment: I noticed that it is the item in view at scroll position that always empty. I am sure why this happend